# WCF configuration for webHttpBinding with SSL terminated at load balancer

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl, wcf-rest

I have a WCF REST service using the webHttpBinding, and I am having some trouble getting it to work in a test environment behind an F5 load balancer - at least I believe the load balancer is an issue.

The service has been proven to run and operate locally using either http or https ("works on my machine"). The service is hosted in the same site that is consuming it.

Our test environment sits behind an F5 load balancer, which terminates SSL and forwards the request to server over http. Our IT staff has indicated that all incoming traffic to the test environment is http, and maintains that the site is configured with both http and https bindings in IIS. The only apparent difference between my local machine and the test environment is that my local machine is IIS 8 and the test environment is IIS 7.5.

The routes are registered like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("REST/stuff", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(StuffService)));
```

Currently, this is the relevant config that works locally:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Initially, this service was deployed to the test environment without SSL, and I received this error when accessing a page that utilized the service:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://foo.bar.com/thing.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://foo.bar.com/REST/stuff/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

That seems mysterious to me now, since the site was accessed over https, and the call to the service was using a relative URL. Unfortunately, I cannot debug this now since I changed the configuration.

At the time I received the error above, I did not know about the F5, and figured that all I needed to do was to configure my service to use transport security, as in the above configuration. After changing configuration to use transport security, the service fails to activate in the test environment, initiating this error on the server:

> The service '/REST/stuff' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

This, I believe, indicates that the service is expecting to operate using https, but the lack of https in registered base address schemes is preventing that, so the service cannot initialize at all.  I understand that this may happen when the https binding is missing in IIS (though IT maintains it is not).

I am not sure what else I can do to enable my use case. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My config was fine. For some reason, when interacting through the load-balancer the client side was not using https when using relative URIs to call services. More information on what I believe to be my problem here: [How to use HTTPS in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839524/how-to-use-https-in-angularjs/27489940#27489940)